# Why doesn't my timer function count down?

Tags: javascript, timer

I am working on a personal project to create a pomodoro clock. I am starting off by trying to create a 25 minute countdown timer with a start and stop button. I have included a timer function that should count down my variable every 1000 milliseconds but it does not function. Here is my HTML:

## Pomodoro Clock

```
<div id="timer" class="circle">Timer</div>
<button onclick="setTimeout(timer, 1000);">Start</button>
<button>Stop</button>
```

Javascript:

```
var i = 25;
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;

function timer(){ 
  setInterval(function(){i--}, 1000);
}
```

I am guessing it may have something to do with my timer function?

Comment: Protip: you're not altering any HTML, so don't use `innerHTML`, use `textContent`

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the **[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** inside the **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** callback. Also you can clear the interval using **[`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval)**. I just removed the **[`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)** , since **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)** starts after the delay.

```js
var i = 25,
  ele = document.getElementById("timer");
ele.innerHTML = i, inter;

function timer() {
  inter = setInterval(function() {
    ele.innerHTML = --i;
    if (i == 0) clearInterval(inter);
  }, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(inter);
}
```

```html
<div id="timer" class="circle">Timer</div>
<button onclick="timer()">Start</button>
<button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;
```

Here the current value of `i` is being assigned to `innerHTML`. It's not being passed by reference.

The only data types in JavaScript that are passed by reference are Objects (Plain objects, functions, arrays, etc).

You need to assign the new value of `i` to `innerHTML` on every iteration of your interval:

```js
setInterval(function(){
    i--;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var i = 25;

function timer(){ 
  setInterval(function(){
    i--;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You have to update your HTML page with this line of code `document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;`

Answer (score 0):

You only set the `innerHTML` one time, at the start of the script. You need to do it each time your function runs.

```
document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;

function timer(){
    setInterval(function(){
        i--;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update the div inside the interval function.

```js
var i = 25;
var timerDiv = document.getElementById("timer");

function timer() {
  setInterval(function() {
    timerDiv.innerHTML = i--;
  }, 1000);
}
```

```css
.circle {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="timer" class="circle">Timer</div>
<button onclick="setTimeout(timer, 1000);">Start</button>
<button>Stop</button>
```